# Hbase API Load documents into Hbase column value

Tags: java, api, hadoop, solr, hbase

I need to load a great deal of documents into hbase for Solr 'Full Text' search, how can I write the whole document content into a column value? Do I still use add? Can I pass my file(s) using put/add? Thank you.